# Zend Framework 2 - Integrate PHP Addendum Library

Tags: php, zend-framework2, google-code

I try to use the [addendum library](http://code.google.com/p/addendum/) with Zend Framework 2 but I failed.

I tried to add it as a module by copying the addedum il to my \module\util directory. It dosent work.

Then I try something else. I copied the directory under \vendor and addendum like that:

```
<?php

// autoload_namespaces.php generated by Composer

$vendorDir = dirname(__DIR__);
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    'Zend\\' => $vendorDir . '/zendframework/zendframework/library/',
    'ZendTest\\' => $vendorDir . '/zendframework/zendframework/tests/',
    'Psr\\Log\\' => $vendorDir . '/psr/log/',
    'Monolog' => $vendorDir . '/monolog/monolog/src/',
    **'Addendum' => $vendorDir . '/addendum/',**
);
```

It dosen't work

So I tried to add it at the end od the init_autoloader.php like this:

```
$loader = new Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader();
$loader->registerNamespace('Addendum', __DIR__ . '/vendor/addendum');
$loader->register();
```

When I try to instantiate a class like this:

```
$foo = new \ReflectionAnnotatedClass($obj);
```

I always have the same error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'ReflectionAnnotatedClass' not found in MyClass.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use composer - and add there:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "zendframework/zendframework": "2.*",
    "niktux/addendum": "dev-master"
}
```

then just php composer.phar install

https://github.com/Niktux/addendum

Then composer autoloader should sort it out for you.

Comment: Working! Will it be the same in ZF1 ?

Comment: I haven't tried, but should be, check this http://adamcod.es/2013/05/10/composer-and-zend-framework-1.x.html